# Which Event should I use to display drawing?

Tags: .net, vb.net, graphics, gdi+

I need to put some graphics in one section of a TableLayoutPanel.

I'm doing this by creating a PictureBox in one cell of the TLP.

Can't get two things to work:

1) The initial display is blank! Drawing appears only when you resize the form

2) The resize event doesn't fire equally when expanding the size as compared contracting.

Any suggestions to improve the above two problems would be great!

Here is my code.  The form has a 2x2 TableLayoutPanel in it, and one cell of the TLP has a PictureBox in it.  Both the TLP and the PictureBox are set to Fill Parent:

```
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D

Public Class Form1
    Private g As Graphics
    Dim n As Integer = 0

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Debug.Print(String.Format("{0}{0}Form1_Load at {1}", vbCrLf, Now()))
    Me.SetDesktopLocation(800, 200)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
    n += 1
    Debug.Print(String.Format("MyBase.Paint: {0}", n))
    DisplayMyStuff()
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Pict    ureBox1.Resize
    n += 1
    Debug.Print(String.Format("PictureBox1.Resize: {0}  PictureBoxSize = {1} / {2}", n, PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height))
    If g IsNot Nothing Then
        g.Dispose()
    End If
    g = PictureBox1.CreateGraphics()
End Sub

Private Sub DisplayMyStuff()
    Dim rect1 As Rectangle
    Dim rect2 As Rectangle
    Dim pt1 As New Point(50, 50)
    Dim pt2 As New Point(100, 100)
    Dim pt3 As New Point(150, 150)
    Dim brR As New SolidBrush(Color.Red)
    Dim linGradBr As New LinearGradientBrush(pt2, pt3, Color.Yellow, Color.Blue)
    Dim pictBoxSize As Size
    Dim sz As Size
    Dim width, height As Integer

    pictBoxSize = New Size(CType(PictureBox1.Size, Point))
    width = CInt(pictBoxSize.Width / 2)
    height = CInt(pictBoxSize.Height / 2)
    sz = New Size(width, height)
    n += 1
    Debug.Print(String.Format("DisplayMyStuff: {0}, Half-Size = {1} / {2}", n, width, height))
    g.Clear(Color.Bisque)
    rect1 = New Rectangle(pt1, sz)
    rect2 = New Rectangle(pt2, sz)
    g.FillRectangle(brR, rect1)
    g.FillRectangle(linGradBr, rect2)
    brR.Dispose()
    linGradBr.Dispose()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Another CreateGraphics() victim.  Anything you draw with "g" will be wiped out again when the picture box repaints itself.  You'll only see the output by accident.  You *must* use the e.Graphics object you get in an event handler for the PictureBox.Paint event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, you are trying to draw to a picturebox (`g = PictureBox1.CreateGraphics()`)

The reason stuff disappears is that when the size changes, or something passes over the window, the controls and form need to be repainted.  This happens in the Paint event, so your code needs to do the drawing there.  Unlike a PictureBox image, items drawn to a form or control are not persistent on their own, that is done by drawing in the Paint event.

This is essentially your DrawMyStuff procedure relocated to the Picbox's Paint event.

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, 
          e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    Dim pt1 As New Point(50, 50)
    Dim pt2 As New Point(100, 100)
    Dim pt3 As New Point(150, 150)

    Dim sz As New Size(CInt(PictureBox1.Size.Width / 2),
                       CInt(PictureBox1.Size.Height / 2))
    n += 1
    Debug.Print(String.Format("DisplayMyStuff: {0}, 
            Half-Size = {1} / {2}", n, sz.Width, sz.Height))

    Dim rect1 As New Rectangle(New Point(50, 50), sz)
    Dim rect2 As New Rectangle(New Point(100, 100), sz)

    Using linGradBr As New LinearGradientBrush(pt2, pt3, Color.Yellow, Color.Blue)

        e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Bisque)

        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rect1)
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rect2)

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, rect1)
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(linGradBr, rect2)

    End Using
End Sub
```

If you are actually trying to paint on the Form, then Grim's answer is the solution.  There you respond to the Form Paint event.  In either case, use the `Graphics` object provided by Windows as an EventArg.

Above, you are using the Graphics object for the PictureBox (via event args) so output is to the PictureBox.

---

Windows wont know you are drawing something in the Paint event, so you need to tell it that the image needs to be updated at certain times such as when the PictureBox is resized.  In the resize event, add:

```
PictureBox1.Invalidate       ' tell windows it needs to be redrawn
' or
PictureBox1.Refresh          ' redraw now
```

`Me.Refresh` is a bit of overkill because the entire form likely does not need to be repainted.

Comment: Well spotted Plutonix ... I missed the fact the paint event was from the form altogether!

Comment: Thanks, very useful. But (see comment below) one question; why don't the rectangles vary in size as the form is resized? The PictureBox is set to DockFill, and the TableLayoutPanel is resizing as the form is resized, but the rectangles are always the same size, despite the fact that sz is varying

Comment: If the picturebox is Dock.Fill to the TLP, and TLP is Dock.Fill to the form and you add `Me.Refresh()` to your picbox Resize event, it should work. Windows doesnt know it needs to redraw the rects because nothing violated that region (IT cant know the rect size depends on the PB size because that is something you provide). So you have to force it to run your code again by telling it to repaint when the size changes using Refresh. If you forced it to repaint the PB (float a window over the form, it would have redrawn).  You may have to play with TLP settings to get the desired effect(s).

Comment: Refresh() does the job nicely! TVM indeed

Comment: @user3012629 your welcome.  Grim's answer would probably have led you to the answer as well, you should acknowledge his efforts by upvoting both answers. (just a suggestion)

Answer (score 1):

As Hans Passant says.  First get rid of;

```
Private g As Graphics
```

and the whole of the `PictureBox1_Resize(...)...` routine.  Then change the following routines to be like so;

```
Private Sub Form1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
    DisplayMyStuff(e.Graphics)
End Sub
```

and

```
Private Sub DisplayMyStuff(pGraphics As Graphics)
    Dim pt1 As New Point(50, 50)
    Dim pt2 As New Point(100, 100)
    Dim pt3 As New Point(150, 150)
    Dim pictBoxSize As New Size(CType(PictureBox1.Size, Point))
    Dim width As Integer = CInt(pictBoxSize.Width / 2)
    Dim height As Integer = CInt(pictBoxSize.Height / 2)
    Dim sz As New Size(width, height)

    pGraphics.Clear(Color.Bisque)

    Dim rect1 As New Rectangle(pt1, sz)
    Dim rect2 As New Rectangle(pt2, sz)
    Using linGradBr As New LinearGradientBrush(pt2, pt3, Color.Yellow, Color.Blue)
        pGraphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, rect1)
        pGraphics.FillRectangle(linGradBr, rect2)
    End Using
End Sub
```

.. then test.  Please report back to tell me that you've learned something!!  Especially.. that you don't need to create a new red brush - all 'standard' colours are built in - and that using the graphics object properly leads to better, smoother displays.

Comment: Yes indeed, learning slowly! ;-)  I did buy a book on GDI+ programming, but it's not good on using the various events. So Hans, Plutonix & Grim, thank you. One thing I still can't get to work though; I've used Plutonix's code; but the drawn rectangles are always the same size.  I was trying to get them to alter in size (half the width & height of the PictureBox) - can't see why they don't change in size...

Comment: Just thought I'd highlight another thing I've learned - how to pass the Graphics event as a parameter to a subroutine - use type "Graphics". Thanks! ;-)