# Having trouble drawing simple rectangle in picturebox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, picturebox, rectangles

I have a picture box that will be showing an image. I want the user to be able to click, drag, and mouse up to a rectangle on the image. Like "I want to do something using this rectangle I drew here on this picture". If they click again, I want the previous rectangle to disappear and they start over or when I click a button to clear the highlighting rectangle they drew.

So I did find some good starting code from the msdn example about creating a zoom in rubber band rectangle that I edited a bit below, but I'm having some issues with:

```
       Public bHaveMouse As Boolean
Public ptOriginal As Point
Public ptLast As Point
Public rect As Rectangle
Public b_Redraw As Boolean = False


' and Normalize the points and draw the reversible frame.
Private Sub MyDrawReversibleRectangle(ByVal p1 As Point, ByVal p2 As Point)
    Try
        'clear 

        ' Convert the points to screen coordinates.
        p1 = PointToScreen(p1)
        p2 = PointToScreen(p2)
        ' Normalize the rectangle.
        If (p1.X < p2.X) Then
            rect.X = p1.X
            rect.Width = p2.X - p1.X
        Else
            rect.X = p2.X
            rect.Width = p1.X - p2.X
        End If
        If (p1.Y < p2.Y) Then
            rect.Y = p1.Y
            rect.Height = p2.Y - p1.Y
        Else
            rect.Y = p2.Y
            rect.Height = p1.Y - p2.Y
        End If

        If rect.Width > pbZoneImage.Width Then
            rect.Width = pbZoneImage.Width
        End If

        If rect.Height > pbZoneImage.Height Then
            rect.Height = pbZoneImage.Height
        End If

        ' Draw the reversible frame.
        ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(rect, Color.Red, FrameStyle.Thick)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub pbZoneImage_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles pbZoneImage.MouseDown
    If e.Button <> Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Try
        ' Make a note that we "have the mouse".
        bHaveMouse = True
        ' Store the "starting point" for this rubber-band rectangle.

        If b_Redraw Then
            If (ptLast.X <> -1) Then
                '     Dim ptCurrent As Point
                'ptCurrent.X = e.X
                'ptCurrent.Y = e.Y
                MyDrawReversibleRectangle(ptOriginal, ptLast)
            End If
            ' Set flags to know that there is no "previous" line to reverse.
            ptLast.X = -1
            ptLast.Y = -1
            ptOriginal.X = -1
            ptOriginal.Y = -1
        End If

        ptOriginal.X = e.X
        ptOriginal.Y = e.Y
        ' Special value lets us know that no previous
        ' rectangle needs to be erased.
        ptLast.X = -1
        ptLast.Y = -1
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub pbZoneImage_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles pbZoneImage.MouseMove
    Dim ptCurrent As Point
    ptCurrent.X = e.X
    ptCurrent.Y = e.Y
    ' If we "have the mouse", then we draw our lines.
    If (bHaveMouse) Then
        ' If we have drawn previously, draw again in
        ' that spot to remove the lines.
        If (ptLast.X <> -1) Then
            MyDrawReversibleRectangle(ptOriginal, ptLast)
        End If
        ' Update last point.
        ptLast = ptCurrent
        ' Draw new lines.
        MyDrawReversibleRectangle(ptOriginal, ptCurrent)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub pbZoneImage_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles pbZoneImage.MouseUp

    'Try
    '    ' Set internal flag to know we no longer "have the mouse".
    bHaveMouse = False

End Sub
```

**My Problem:**  Sometimes when drawing it *doesn't* remove the previously drawn rectangle, or if I hover over certain buttons (like the exit button) the rectangles disappear! I want they to stay so that I can record the start and end point of the rectangle for other programs. I want them to disappear when I hit my clear rectangle button, but I feel like I am getting confused on something that should be very simple.

Another issue is I'm trying to keep the rectangle from spilling outside the picture box (Pbzoneimage). But it does, and changes color.

Where did I go wrong? Is there is a better way to draw this altogether?

Comment: do all painting in the paint event...that is the code to draw can be where you have it, but it needs to be invoked from the Paint event.  You need a class or Rectangle var to track the current image to paint/draw

Comment: So, If I have to do it with the paint event, how would I move my drawing function into that? Should I call it from my mouse up event? or possibly hover?

Comment: you dont have to move it, just call it from there.  See  [this explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24933350/1070452) for more info.  Sounds like you mostly just need to update a Rectangle variable and force it to repaint now and them using `picturebox.invalidate`

Comment: So, other than redraw it in the paint, will this solve the fact that my rectangles disappear when I hover over the exit button?

Answer (score 2):

You need two bitmaps, one for the picturebox (img) and one to clear it and draw the rectangle(imgClone).

```
Private mouse_Down As Point
Private img As Bitmap
Private imgClone As Bitmap

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    img = My.Resources..... 'or you can load the image from file

    PictureBox1.Image = img 'with this every time you invalidate it draws img to picturebox

    imgClone = CType(PictureBox1.Image.Clone, Bitmap)

End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
    mouse_Down = e.Location
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left And e.Location <> mouse_Down Then
        DrawRectangle(e.Location)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DrawRectangle(ByVal pnt As Point)
    Dim g As Graphics

    g = Graphics.FromImage(img)

    g.DrawImage(imgClone, 0, 0) 'we are clearing img with imgClone. imgClone contains the original image without the rectangles

    If pnt.X = mouse_Down.X Or pnt.Y = mouse_Down.Y Then
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Firebrick, mouse_Down.X, mouse_Down.Y, pnt.X, pnt.Y)

    Else
        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Firebrick, Math.Min(mouse_Down.X, pnt.X), Math.Min(mouse_Down.Y, pnt.Y),
                    Math.Abs(mouse_Down.X - pnt.X), Math.Abs(mouse_Down.Y - pnt.Y))

    End If

    g.Dispose()

    PictureBox1.Invalidate() 'draw img to picturebox
End Sub
```

If you need to clear the picturebox:

```
Dim g As Graphics

g = Graphics.FromImage(img)
g.DrawImage(imgClone, 0, 0)

g.Dispose()

PictureBox1.Invalidate()
```

valter

Comment: So, it took me a while for this one, since it turns out it is so small you don't actually see the thin red line. But Mostly because I think it's drawing based on the mouse point and not the relative picture box location. Other wise, I think this is a interesting solution.

Comment: @sparkysword If you want a thicker line use a custom pen *Private myPen As Pen = New Pen(Color.Red, 3)* instead of *Pens.Red*. I dont understand *...based on the mouse point and not the relative picture box location*.

Comment: So I basically have to drag the mouse outside of my control onto my second monitor to make the red square as big as the picture box, which is only about 500x500.

Comment: @sparkysword Your question was *drawing simple rectangle in picturebox*. Do you want to draw on picturebox or on the screen?