# Resizing drawn rectangle on Picturebox relative to image using Zoom

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

I have a Picturebox that I can draw a rectangle on and I have it so that the rectangle dimensions, in percent, are logged so that if the size of the form changes, then so does the rectangle size (see code below the text)

However, when I have the Picturebox in "Zoom" mode, the rectangle does not match up when resizing (see here: First one, with corners on defined points on image http://i1262.photobucket.com/albums/ii602/bmgh85/Size1.png and then second one after resizing the form http://i1262.photobucket.com/albums/ii602/bmgh85/Size2.png

It works fine in "Stretch" mode, but that skews the images, which is no use to me (I need to keep the proportions). How can I manipulate my code to get it to work as intended?

```
Private x, y As Integer
Private Rct As New Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0)

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        x = e.X
        y = e.Y
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        Rct.X = Math.Min(x, e.X)
        Rct.Y = Math.Min(y, e.Y)
        Rct.Height = Math.Abs(e.Y - y)
        Rct.Width = Math.Abs(e.X - x)
        PictureBox1.Refresh()
        PictureBox1.Tag = calculatePercent(Rct.X, Rct.Y, Rct.Height, Rct.Width, PictureBox1)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseUp
    MsgBox(PictureBox1.Tag)
    Dim lst1 As List(Of Int32) = returnPercent(PictureBox1.Tag)
    For i = 0 To lst1.Count - 1
        MsgBox(lst1(i))
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, Rct)
End Sub

Function calculatePercent(ByVal X As Long, Y As Long, Ht As Long, Wth As Long, pBox As PictureBox)
    Dim wPercent As Long = 100 * Wth / pBox.Width
    Dim hPercent As Long = 100 * Ht / pBox.Height
    Dim yPercent As Long = 100 * Y / pBox.Height
    Dim xPercent As Long = 100 * X / pBox.Width
    Return "X:" & xPercent & ", Y:" & yPercent & ", Ht:" & hPercent & ", Wth:" & wPercent
End Function

Function returnPercent(ByVal myTag As String)
    Dim lst As New List(Of Int32)
    Dim getX As String = getNum(Mid(myTag, InStr(myTag, "X:"), InStr(myTag, ", Y:") - InStr(myTag, "X:")))
    Dim getY As String = getNum(Mid(myTag, InStr(myTag, ", Y:"), InStr(myTag, ", Ht:") - InStr(myTag, ", Y:")))
    Dim getH As String = getNum(Mid(myTag, InStr(myTag, ", Ht:"), InStr(myTag, ", Wth:") - InStr(myTag, ", Ht:")))
    Dim getW As String = getNum(Mid(myTag, InStr(myTag, ", Wth:")))
    lst.Add(getX)
    lst.Add(getY)
    lst.Add(getH)
    lst.Add(getW)
    Return lst
End Function

Function getNum(ByVal txt As String)
    Dim rtn As String = vbNullString
    Dim coln As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(txt, "\d+")
    For Each mtch As Match In coln
        rtn = rtn & mtch.ToString
    Next
    Return Convert.ToInt32(rtn)
End Function

Private Sub PictureBox1_SizeChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.SizeChanged
    Dim lst As New List(Of Int32)
    If PictureBox1.Tag <> "" Then
        lst = returnPercent(PictureBox1.Tag)
        Rct.X = lst(0) * PictureBox1.Width / 100
        Rct.Y = lst(1) * PictureBox1.Height / 100
        Rct.Height = lst(2) * PictureBox1.Height / 100
        Rct.Width = lst(3) * PictureBox1.Width / 100
        PictureBox1.Refresh()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: We're twins! I had a very similar question earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26471376/drawing-rect-in-picturebox-not-done-to-right-scale-for-mouse

Comment: Although the questions are different, I think your issue is that you're not drawing directly on the image using graphics.fromimage (which is recommended by a lot over the e.graphics). I'd try that, and the rect will be resized with your image automatically (since it's drawn on the bitmap).

Comment: The problem with that is I use the image in 3 other places elsewhere on the form, but only want to have this instance have the rectangle on it (hence my need to do this and store the percent values to call back again later). If I do this, then wouldnt it involve saving out the original and edited images meaning more space used on disk? Or would it still give me the desired effect on only that instance and still be called up on the fly?

Comment: It would involve saving a copy bitmap/image, yes. But I ended up doing that with my photos (which can go up to 1980x680) and didn't see a lag or big space issue. But, I don't know what your requirement is.

Comment: My boss is VERY particular about hard drive footprint. If something can be saved smaller then it MUST be (often at the expense of quality - he doesn't have much knowledge in IT or graphics). Think I may have just thought of a solution though. If I use Zoom, I should still be able to get the image dimensions (not picturebox) and work out % from that instead. Quick aside, what are you using for the camera in your app in your question? Started putting a camera addin on something I am working on but suffering a lot with using API calls as these are temperamental with drivers on anything above XP

Comment: Well if size is a problem, then reference one of the other three "good" or original instances of the image. You can always use Dispose() to keep memory tight when you're done with it. The camera is a network security camera. They usually use HTTP commands to communicate to the device directly.

Answer (score 0):

I have some code that might help you:

```
    ' Rectangle to draw
Private Rct As New Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0)
Private offsetX As Integer = 0
Private offsetY As Integer = 0

Sub Main() Handles MyBase.Load

    ' Some image to use
    MiniPictureBox.Image = My.Resources.P6130003
    MainPictureBox.Image = My.Resources.P6130003

End Sub

Private Sub MiniPictureBox_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MiniPictureBox.MouseDown

    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then

        If Not Rct.Contains(e.Location) Then
            ' New rectangle
            Rct.Location = New Point(e.X, e.Y)
        Else
            ' Moving a rectangle
            offsetX = Rct.X - e.X
            offsetY = Rct.Y - e.Y
        End If

    ElseIf e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then

        ' Clears the screen of a rectangle
        Rct = New Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0)
        MiniPictureBox.Invalidate()

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub MiniPictureBox_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MiniPictureBox.MouseMove

    ' Event handler to update the picture of the rectangle
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then

        If Rct.Contains(e.Location) Then
            ' Move the box
            Rct.X = e.X + offsetX
            Rct.Y = e.Y + offsetY
            MainPictureBox.Invalidate()
        Else
            ' Update the size of the box
            Rct.Width = e.X - Rct.X
            Rct.Height = e.Y - Rct.Y
        End If

        MiniPictureBox.Invalidate()

    End If


End Sub

Private Sub MiniPictureBox_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MiniPictureBox.MouseUp

    ' Event handler to call the paint event for runtime display
    MiniPictureBox.Invalidate()
    MainPictureBox.Invalidate()

End Sub

Private Sub MiniPictureBox_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles MiniPictureBox.Paint

    Dim myPen As Pen = New Pen(Brushes.Red, 2)
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(myPen, Rct)

End Sub

Private Sub MainPictureBox_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles MainPictureBox.Paint

    If Rct.Width > 0 Then
        Dim biggerRec As Rectangle = CalculateRectangle(MainPictureBox)

        Dim myPen As Pen = New Pen(Brushes.Red, 2)
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(myPen, biggerRec)
    End If

End Sub

Private Function CalculateRectangle(currentPicture As PictureBox) As Rectangle

    Try
        Dim newWidth As Integer = (Rct.Width / MiniPictureBox.Width) * currentPicture.Image.Width
        Dim newHeight As Integer = (Rct.Height / MiniPictureBox.Height) * currentPicture.Image.Height
        Dim newX As Integer = (Rct.X / MiniPictureBox.Width) * currentPicture.Image.Width
        Dim newY As Integer = (Rct.Y / MiniPictureBox.Height) * currentPicture.Image.Height
        Return New Rectangle(newX, newY, newWidth, newHeight)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace)
    End Try

End Function
```

This code will allow you to create, move, and clear a rectangle. One point of caution is in the calculations for changing the size of the rectangle, you have to ensure exception handling is properly inserted for any arithmetic exceptions.