# How to prevent graphics from resetting

Tags: vb.net, graphics, graphics2d

I looked for an answer online but I keep ending with results like "How to reset graphics" instead, there don't seem to be any answers in here as well regarding this matter.

When I use this method to draw graphics on a picture box:

```
Dim Gr As Graphics = QArea.CreateGraphics()
Gr.DrawString("University Name Here", FontSampleB.Font, Brushes.Black, 15, 10)
```

My graphics get reset often when I minimize the application, or move it outside screen borders. Is there any way to avoid this?

I tried `Graphis.Save()` but I guess that's not what it's for.

Comment: Dont use CreateGraphics and do your painting in the paint event to make your drawing/image persist

Comment: @Plutonix Thank you, if you post this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: *You* dont trigger it.  When something invalidates the PictureBox's (or whatever) area Windows will fire the PaintEvent.  If your code is there, it will get updated as needed.   There are hundreds if not thousands of copies of the answer here already...[such as here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24933350/1070452)

Comment: Glad you got it to work!